# IIS 10 Reverse proxy throws 404 over images

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, iis-10, arr

I've followed this excellent guide on how to setup a IIS 10 reverse proxy to open up my backend akeneo server from the internet.

(this one: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/IIS-Support-Blog/Setup-IIS-with-URL-Rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world/ba-p/846222#M343)

It works fine, except that I doesn't show images. I see 404 errors in the IIS log for all jpg files (1 line underneath is 404 on image file, the second line is a normal 200 one)

```
2019-11-07 14:26:30 192.168.1.253 GET /media/show/1%2F8%2F8%2F8%2F188838fd29a44f7eed902ebfe51926bcbf4fe24b_90036_Herbovet_Herbintest_1_L.jpg/thumbnail_small - 80 - 81.241.239.100 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/78.0.3904.87+Safari/537.36 http://ake.xxx.be/ 404 11 0 1
2019-11-07 14:26:30 192.168.1.253 GET /configuration/attribute-option/attribute/nett_content_unit/option options%5Bidentifiers%5D%5B%5D=liter&X-ARR-CACHE-HIT=0&X-ARR-LOG-ID=6d444c39-ea68-407a-969d-5ae2c5fcaad8&SERVER-STATUS=200 80 - 81.241.239.100 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/78.0.3904.87+Safari/537.36 http://ake.xxx.be/ 200 0 0 246
```

This is on Windows Server 2019, IIS 10. The backend is Apache on Ubuntu 18.04 running Akeneo.

This is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://192.168.1.252/{R:1}" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                    </serverVariables>
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://192.168.1.252/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://ake.xxx.be/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RestoreAcceptEncoding" preCondition="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                    <match serverVariable="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" pattern="^(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                    <preCondition name="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                        <add input="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern=".+" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
        <caching>
            <profiles>
                <add extension=".jpg" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="DisableCache" />
            </profiles>
        </caching>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Please let me know If you need more info. 
Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Run some basic analysis via FRT then, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: 404.11 - Request contains a double escape sequence. you could enable by using iis request filtering feature->edit feature setting->check allow double escaping [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IXdJ.png).also, refer this link:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosag/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr/

Answer (score 0):

404.11 - Request contains a double escape sequence.
To resolve the issue you could try this below steps:

1)open iis manager select site.

2)Click on the request filtering feature. select edit feature setting from the action pane.

3)check the allow double escaping.

[image]

also, refer this link for more detail:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosag/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr/

Comment: Hello, This does not seem to be the case. I've checked this box but it still doesn't work. But I also do not have any request filtering rule, should I have one? If so, how should it look like?

Comment: @Tom no need to add request filtering rule. just need to enable allow double escaping to true. after doing this restart the iis server and site and hard refresh the site in the browser. does your mage name contain any special characters?

Comment: Hello Jalpa, thanks for your comment. I investigated again, and now noticed I no longer get 404, but http 400 errors on the images. Not sure what changed though. I activated the failed request tracing, and managed to generate logfiles on the errors. However, the FRT log show no errors or warnings in the request summary? I do see that there is a mix of / and %2F in the request url (see my initial post). Any idea on how to proceed next? I'd like to share a FRT logfile, but I am not sure that doing this here in the forum is the safest way...

Comment: @Tom is your site is public-facing? can you please check the iis log for the sub status code. make sure you enable failed request tracing as shown in [iamge](https://i.imgur.com/IaLysNV.png)

Comment: hello, yes the site is public facing. the protocol substatus code is 0. The FRT settings are indeed set like that, and  FRT logfiles are being generated, if you want I wouldn't mind sending one of them to you via private message if this is feasable via this site. I also notice that the problem only seems to occur with this type of url: /media/show/9%2F4%2Fd%2F7%2F94d7329214e6ea39d4299acf21e6648321f89b6e_81023_Winners_Winchol_500_ml.jpg/thumbnail_small, because other images (like /bitnami/images/corner-logo.png ) are displayed correctly.

Comment: @Tom try to add the `<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="500" />
</system.web>` in your web.config file.

Comment: or increase max url maxAllowedContentLength in request filtering [image](https://i.imgur.com/Ig57kO1.png).

Comment: hi, I tried both suggestions and restarted the iis site, but no change i'm afraid. I'm about to try a apache reverse proxy setup if I can't get this working. Unless you have another suggestion? BTW, some on the akeneo support site, added this piece of info: "your proxy probably have filtered the authentication headers or the session cookies", could that be useful to you?